# Dynamically restructuring an array of objects each containing two property value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm drawing data from a database and ending up with an array of objects each containing waiter names and the the days they have worked.  I want to dynamically restructure the array by condensing it to a single object with two property value pairs per waiter.  One property for the name and another for the days working.

I am really curious to see your feedback.  I started off by extracting the names and removing duplicates.  Leaving me with an array like this: `let waiterNames = ['John','Mark','Jess'].`

Then I was attempting a double for of loop and somehow creating a new array of objects, but I'm stuck.

```
for (entry in waiterInfo) {
    for (waiter in waiterNames) {
        if (entry.waiters == waiter) {
        ???
        }
    }
}
```

`waiterInfo` is what I start with, `newInfo` is what I want to achieve.  I need this to happen dynamically because the data drawn from the database is unpredictable.

```
let waiterInfo = [{ waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Monday' },
{ waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },
{ waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Wednesday' },
{ waiters: 'Mark', weekdays: 'Monday' },
{ waiters: 'Mark', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },
{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Monday' },
{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },
{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Wednesday' },
{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Thursday' }]
```

```
let newInfo = [{ waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday'},
{ waiters: 'Mark', weekdays: 'Monday, Tuesday' },
{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday' }]
```

Comment: Can you show what the array you get from the DB looks like?

Comment: Hi, thank you four reply.  The array is shown above - waiterInfo.  I want to change it dynamically to look like newInfo.

Comment: Which DB do you use? Perhaps it would be easier to do this thing directly in the db.

Comment: This is a valid point - but I was curious to see how to solve this problem anyhow.  I'm using postgreSQL.
My table has four columns: id, waiter_username, weekdays_working and waiters_id which is unique for each waiter.

I was attempting to write a query that would remove the duplicate waiters names, but was unsuccessful.  This is the query I used which returned the waiterInfo array above -> `select waiter_username as waiters, weekdays_working as weekdays from waiters order by waiter_username;`

Comment: @Warwick: `select waiter_username, array_agg(weekdays_working) as weekdays from waiters group by waiter_username` should do the trick.

Comment: @georg Excellent -it worked! Now I have information on how to do it both ways! Yours, arguably, being the simplest of all! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a map alongside `reduce`:

```js
let waiterInfo = [{ waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Monday' },
  { waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },
  { waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Wednesday' },
  { waiters: 'Mark', weekdays: 'Monday' },
  { waiters: 'Mark', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },
  { waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Monday' },
  { waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },
  { waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Wednesday' },
  { waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Thursday' }
]


const map = new Map()

const newInfo = waiterInfo.reduce((a, o) => {
  const i = map.get(o.waiters)
  if(i !== undefined) {
    a[i].weekdays = [a[i].weekdays, o.weekdays].join(', ')
  } else {
    map.set(o.waiters, a.push(o) - 1)
  }
  return a
}, [])

console.log(newInfo)
```

This code's time complexity is O(*n*), since we are using a map.

(Also, this is one of the only times I've seen `push`'s return value be useful )

Comment: Incredible - you guys are very good.  I am very inspired by your feedback!

Comment: @Warwick No problem, glad to help. If you need more help, be it understanding how this code works or anything else, feel free to ask.

Comment: I'm going on lunch now.. will attempt implementing and understanding the code into my program afterwards.  Will post a question here if I don't understand - but think I can figure it out with all the information I've obtained in this thread. Thank you. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const waiterInfo = [{ waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Monday' },{ waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },{ waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Wednesday' },{ waiters: 'Mark', weekdays: 'Monday' },{ waiters: 'Mark', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Monday' },{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Wednesday' },{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Thursday' },]

const result = Object
  .values(
    waiterInfo.reduce((a, { waiters, weekdays }) => {
      a[waiters] = a[waiters] || { waiters, weekdays: [] }
      a[waiters].weekdays.push(weekdays)
      return a
    }, {})
  )
  .map(({ waiters, weekdays }) => ({ waiters, weekdays: weekdays.join(', ') }))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use a temporary `Map` to keep track of the objects for the waiters you've seen before, so you can add to their list of days.

```
const waiterMap = new Map();
const newInfo = [];
for (const {waiters, weekdays} of waiterInfo) {
    let entry = waiterMap.get(waiters);
    if (!entry) {
        // New waiter, create the object and put it in the map and result array
        const copy = {waiters, weekdays};
        waiterMap.set(waiters, copy);
        newInfo.push(copy);
    } else {
        // Existing entry, just add to it
        entry.weekdays += `, ${weekdays}`;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let waiterInfo = [{ waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Monday' },
{ waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },
{ waiters: 'John', weekdays: 'Wednesday' },
{ waiters: 'Mark', weekdays: 'Monday' },
{ waiters: 'Mark', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },
{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Monday' },
{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Tuesday' },
{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Wednesday' },
{ waiters: 'Jess', weekdays: 'Thursday' }];

const waiterMap = new Map();
const newInfo = [];
for (const {waiters, weekdays} of waiterInfo) {
    let entry = waiterMap.get(waiters);
    if (!entry) {
        // New waiter, create the object and put it in the map and result array
        const copy = {waiters, weekdays};
        waiterMap.set(waiters, copy);
        newInfo.push(copy);
    } else {
        // Existing entry, just add to it
        entry.weekdays += `, ${weekdays}`;
    }
}

console.log(newInfo);
```

That avoids modifying the existing data, but you could reuse the original object if you don't care about `waiterInfo` once you're done.

Comment: T.J. Crowder magnificent! I am very impressed by your speed.